# How to get Crashlytics event from BigQuery[Firebase project]

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, crashlytics

We have enabled BigQuery feature for our Firebase project , since last week firebase team announced that Crashlytics is moved from Beta to Prod release , so I was thinking this data should be available in BigQuery in some form. But I was not able to see any Crash event in my BigQuery table even the app crashed a couple of time. So does anybody know how to extract the crashlytics report from Firebase for custom reporting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics data is not currently available in BigQuery but we are looking into this in the near future. Please stay tuned :D

Comment: HI what about cloud functions for crashlytics I am also not able to deploy crashlytics for cloud functions which is mentioned in official docs

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old now but for the benefit of those who end up here when searching the web, please see below:

It seems like Crashlytics data is now available for export into Big Query. You will need to link your Crashlytics account with your Firebase project, which requires admin rights from Crashlytics side. Have a look at the following links as a starting point:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/exporting-crashlytics-data-to-bigquery.html

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery#working_with_firebase_crashlytics_data_in_bigquery

On the second link you may need to scroll back to the top and read the 'Before you begin' section.

Hope that helps.