# Firebase crashlytics not exported to BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-crash-reporting

I am linking Firebase reports to BigQuery.
Analytics tables are exported to BigQuery, but Crashlytics tables are not exported to BigQuery.
Account grade is a free sandbox.
It will not be exported even if about 3 days have passed since the export was valid.

[bigquery state image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw3lZ.png)

The settings were made with reference to the procedure. crashlytics export is also valid.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export?hl=EN

How do I export crashlytics reports to BigQuery?

Comment: I found this blog which details how to do this ["Exporting Crashlytics data to BigQuery"](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/exporting-crashlytics-data-to-bigquery.html). Also you could take a look in this Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420530/how-to-get-crashlytics-event-from-bigqueryfirebase-project)

Comment: I also saw this blog and the stack overflow report. But the problem is not solved. I think the procedure is correct.

Comment: I suggest you to reach directly the [Firebase Support team](https://firebase.google.com/support), if they give you an answer, please share it  with us.

Comment: It is solved.
First, I deleted all the datasets that were linked to Firebase in BigQuery.
Next, when relinking from Firebase, Crashlytics data flowed in.
Maybe the sandbox version doesn't work yet. I didn't work because I first worked with sandbox.
I think it will work if you work with the Blaze plan.

Comment: I had to disable and enable the Crashlytics export in the integrations page in Firebase console to make it work